# UML : How to Show Calling Methods of One Class and The Interaction Between Them in One

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram

I want to show the interaction between methods of one class and sequence of calling them in uml diagram. is the sequence diagram suitable for this scenario? is activity diagram suitable? what name and stereotype i have to select for entity?

for example my class is C which has 3 methods M1, M2, M3. first method M1 will be invoked in class and second M2. the result of M1 is a input parameter for m2. then M3 will be invoked and the result of M2 is a input for M3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity and  Interaction Overview can be used for planning logic inside one class, or some classes/components.

Sequence and Time diagrams don't even know, if the methods they are planning are in one class or different ones - it is irrelevant for them.

Also look for composite structure diagram - it is for inner class structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sequence diagram or Activity diagram. In Activity diagram use Call Operation actions. No stereotype is necessary to use.